# Re-evaluating a var in python

Tags: python

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
class Atrribute(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.value = 0
   def get():
       self.value = random(10)

def func(var):
   lambda var: return var+1

1) myFunc = func(Attribute().get())
2) myFunc()
3) myFunc()
```

Now, when I call myFunc() in line 2 I get a random value from 0 to 10 (plus one) which was produced by the get() function in Attribute. The problem is that when I call myFunc() in line 3, I get the same random value from line 2. Is there anyway I can make python initiate the get() function again on line 3 to produce a new random value?

Meir

Comment: That code doesn't even _close_ to work. Please rewrite is as a _working example_. The class name is spelled wrong. You can't create `get` without an argument unless you make it a `staticmethod` and you can't call an instance method on the class unless you manually pass it an instance of the class. `func` doesn't return a callable so `myFunc()` won't work. `get` returns `None` so that's what you're passing to `func` -- you can't add to `None`.

Comment: The get() method is not returning anything and is not being passed self.  Is this your actual code?

Comment: Also random is undefined (and doesn't act like the obvious `random.random`), you can't return inside lambda, and attribute is misspelled.. Changed the word "code" to "pseudo-code!"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is:

```
import random

class Attribute(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.value = 0
   def get(self):
       self.value = random.random() * 10
       return self.value

def func(fn):
   return lambda: fn() + 1

att = Attribute()
myFunc = func(att.get)
print myFunc()
print myFunc()
```

In future, please make sure that any code that you post is free of syntax errors and actually does what you say it does.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def myFunc():
    return random(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code (if written correctly and as I believe you intended it) would only call Attribute.get() once,, on lin 1.  Then assigns the value returned to the variable 'myFunc'.

Try this instead:

```
class Atrribute(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.value = 0
   def get():
       self.value = random(10)

def func(var):
   return var+1

1) a = Attribute()
2) myFunc = a.get
3) func(myFunc)
4) func(myFunc)
```